# How to filter information depending on a parameter in bash

Tags: bash, filter

I want to filter the output of a command in a specific way. Let's suppose the following output:

```
==== Foo ====
Line to filter 1
Line to filter 2
Line to filter 3
Line to filter 4
Line to filter 5
==== Bar ====
Line to filter 6
Line to filter 7
Line to filter 8
Line to filter 9
Line to filter 10
```

What I'm trying to do is to filter with one command the `Lines to filter 1-5` depending if the "parameter" in the command is Foo or Bar. For example:

`command | grep '... Foo ...'`, output:

```
Line to filter 1
Line to filter 2
Line to filter 3
Line to filter 4
Line to filter 5
```

`command | grep '... Bar ...'`, output:

```
Line to filter 6
Line to filter 7
Line to filter 8
Line to filter 9
Line to filter 10
```

Is there a possible way to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways you could do this.  Using awk:

```
awk -v s="Foo" '/^=/&&$2!=s { p=0 } p==1; /^=/&&$2==s { p=1 }' input.txt
```

This uses a marker, `p`, that gets toggled based on the content of any header line it finds.

A second approach (brazenly stolen from from 123's deleted answer, which I liked) is much shorter:

```
awk -v s="$var" '/^=/{p=$0~s;next} p'
```

This awk script has two expressions - the first sets `p` to the boolean result of the evaluation `$0~s`, and the second prints the line if `p` is true. `p` only changes on header lines. I can't think of a shorter way to express this task in awk.

An approach in `sed` might be:

```
sed -ne '/^==== Foo/,/^====/{;/^====/d;p;}' input.txt
```

But you can't pass variables in to sed, so you'd be rewriting your actual script for this, which is a little uglier. If you wanted to sanitize your input in bash, you could do so using *parameter expansion*. For example, you could *strip* any non-alphanumeric characters, if you're pretty sure that's what you expect to see in titles:

```
s="##Fo@o! "
sed -ne "/^==== ${s//[^[:alnum:]]/}/,/^====/{;/^====/d;p;}" input.txt
```

Of course, `sed` and `awk` are available *from* bash, but they don't represent bash scripting. This could be done in bash alone, too:

```
s="Foo"; p=false
while read line; do 
  [[ $line =~ ^==== ]] && p=false
  $p && echo "$line"
  [[ $line =~ ^====\ $s ]] && p=true
done < input.txt
```

This follows the example of the `awk` script above, setting a boolean which gets toggled depending on what header we see.